# How to check if a value contain percentage then discount it with percentage else use its original value?

Tags: jquery

I am doing a discount function, user can type the discount amount such as if user input 10 then it become 50(item price)-10=40, if user input 10%, the result is 50-10%=45.

I had try the following code. It can different whether the value contain % symbol or not, but if it contain then the value become NaN. I know it cannot recognize the symbol when do the calculation so it become NaN, but how do I make it to ignore the % symbol? And it is also change when I on input the discount.
Thank you.

```js
$("#table_invoice").on("input", '.dt_discount', function() {
  calculate_subTotal($(this).closest('.dt_row'));
})

function calculate_subTotal(row) {
  var unitCost = $(row).find(".dt_unitPrice").val();
  var qty = $(row).find(".dt_qty").val();
  var discount = $(row).find(".dt_discount").val();

  if (discount.indexOf("%") > -1) {

    var row_total = Number(unitCost * qty * (1 - (discount / 100)));
  } else {
    var row_total = Number((unitCost * qty) - discount);
  }


  $(row).find(".dt_subtotal").val(row_total);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table_invoice">
  <row class="dt_row">
    Price<input class="form-control form-price dt_unitPrice" name="dt_unitPrice" value="50"></br>
    Qty<input class="form-control form-quantity dt_qty" name="dt_qty" value="2"></br>
    Discount<input class="form-control form-discount dt_discount" name="dt_discount" value="0"></br>
    Total<input class="form-control form-price dt_subtotal" name="dt_subtotal" value="0.00">
  </row>
</div>
```

Comment: try to remove it , 10+Number(String(value_with_%).replace('%', '')) = 40

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Got it, Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse discount if it contains percent.

```js
$("#table_invoice").on("input", '.dt_discount', function() {
  calculate_subTotal($(this).closest('.dt_row'));
})

function calculate_subTotal(row) {
  var unitCost = $(row).find(".dt_unitPrice").val();
  var qty = $(row).find(".dt_qty").val();
  var discount = $(row).find(".dt_discount").val();

  if (discount.indexOf("%") > -1) {
    discount = parseInt(discount, 10); // <-- here

    var row_total = Number(unitCost * qty * (1 - (discount / 100)));
  } else {
    var row_total = Number((unitCost * qty) - discount);
  }


  $(row).find(".dt_subtotal").val(row_total);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table_invoice">
  <row class="dt_row">
    Price<input class="form-control form-price dt_unitPrice" name="dt_unitPrice" value="50"></br>
    Qty<input class="form-control form-quantity dt_qty" name="dt_qty" value="2"></br>
    Discount<input class="form-control form-discount dt_discount" name="dt_discount" value="0"></br>
    Total<input class="form-control form-price dt_subtotal" name="dt_subtotal" value="0.00">
  </row>
</div>
```

Comment: @Beginner  Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/p5jm98yj/1/

```js
$("#table_invoice").on("input", '.dt_discount', function() {
  calculate_subTotal($(this).closest('.dt_row'));
})

function calculate_subTotal(row) {
  var unitCost = $(row).find(".dt_unitPrice").val();
  var qty = $(row).find(".dt_qty").val();
  var discount = $(row).find(".dt_discount").val();

  if (discount.indexOf("%") > -1) {

    var row_total = Number(unitCost * qty * (1 - (parseFloat(discount) / 100)));
  } else {
    var row_total = Number((unitCost * qty) - discount);
  }


  $(row).find(".dt_subtotal").val(row_total);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table_invoice">
  <row class="dt_row">
    Price<input class="form-control form-price dt_unitPrice" name="dt_unitPrice" value="50"><br/>
    Qty<input class="form-control form-quantity dt_qty" name="dt_qty" value="2"><br/>
    Discount<input class="form-control form-discount dt_discount" name="dt_discount" value="0"><br/>
    Total<input class="form-control form-price dt_subtotal" name="dt_subtotal" value="0.00">
  </row>
</div>
```

It will work for decimal values like 12.5% as well.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#table_invoice").on("input", '.dt_discount', function() {
  calculate_subTotal($(this).closest('.dt_row'));
})

function calculate_subTotal(row) {
  var unitCost = $(row).find(".dt_unitPrice").val();
  var qty = $(row).find(".dt_qty").val();
  var discount = $(row).find(".dt_discount").val();

  if (discount.indexOf("%") > -1) {
     discount=discount.replace("%", '');
 discount=parseInt(discount);
    var row_total = Number(unitCost * qty * (1 - (discount / 100)));
  } else {
    var row_total = Number((unitCost * qty) - discount);
  }


  $(row).find(".dt_subtotal").val(row_total);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table_invoice">
  <row class="dt_row">
    Price<input class="form-control form-price dt_unitPrice" name="dt_unitPrice" value="50"></br>
    Qty<input class="form-control form-quantity dt_qty" name="dt_qty" value="2"></br>
    Discount<input class="form-control form-discount dt_discount" name="dt_discount" value="0"></br>
    Total<input class="form-control form-price dt_subtotal" name="dt_subtotal" value="0.00">
  </row>
</div>
```